# Getting Exception System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'System.Windows.Rect System.Windows.Automation.... in in TestStackWhite Application

Tags: c#, mstest, visual-studio-2019, teststack

I am writing a test method to launch a window application.

Below is my code

```
 namespace UnitTestProject1
    {
        [TestClass]
        public class UnitTest1
        {
            [TestMethod]
            public void TestMethod1()
            {      
                ProcessStartInfo P = new ProcessStartInfo("C:\\Windows\\System32\\notepad.exe");
                Application app = Application.Launch(P);      
            }
        }
    }
```

After running this test a Notepad window opens up and then below exception is thrown

> System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'System.Windows.Rect
>   System.Windows.Automation.Provider.IRawElementProviderFragment.get_BoundingRectangle()

Comment: Have you tried this: `Application app = Application.Launch("C:\\Windows\\System32\\notepad.exe");`?

Comment: @EvgeniyChiruk same exception with Application.Launch(AppPath) also.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what namespace `Application` belongs but it's probably the wrong one and you are aiming for the class `Process`. Below is the code you need to perform this task with the method `.Run()`.

```
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace UnitTestProject1
        {
            [TestClass]
            public class UnitTest1
            {
                [TestMethod]
                public void TestMethod1()
                {      
                    ProcessStartInfo P = new ProcessStartInfo("C:\\Windows\\System32\\notepad.exe");
                    Process.Start(P);      
                }
            }
        }
```